# change byte[] to inputstream?

Tags: java, android, arrays, inputstream, libraries

I'm using two libraries in an android app I'm trying to make. New to android. The app is for connecting to serial devices and controlling their console via a terminal.

One library is for setting up a serial connection, setting baud rate etc. and can also write read/data over serial.. The other is for creating a terminal session. My problem lies in incorporating both of these together to have a terminal that is connected to a serial device.

In the terminal library I need to supply an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to provide input and output to the terminal. So I have to call `setTermIn(java.io.InputStream)` and `setTermOut(java.io.OutputStream)` to connect the input and output streams to the emulator.

In the serial library however there are two methods for sending and receiving and these deal with arrays of bytes. 
`sendData(byte[] data)` for sending data and a dataListener for receiving data. I have to implement this and code the method `onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data)` with id being the name of the device.

I don't have source code for the function that sends an array of bytes over serial, so how do I make the array of bytes into a stream to send to my terminal?

**EDIT:**

I think this should override it and that is what I want?

```
Private USB2SerialAdapter mSelectedAdapter;

...

public void sendData(byte[] data)
{
//this should echo what I send to the terminal in the correct format
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);     

bos.write(data, 0, data.length);

setTermOut(bos);

//send data over serial using original sendData() method
mSelectedAdapter.sendData(data);
}
```

Comment: `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two snippets should give you enough information to find a solution to your problem.

**reading:**

```
byte[] source = ...;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(source);
// read bytes from bis ...
```

**writing**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// write bytes to bos ...
byte[] sink = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: @Blacklight I Couldn't figure out how to format code in a comment so I edited the original question. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it: [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html), [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Just look at the docs in those cases.